# How can I add an error message to my program if the user doesn't enter an integer?

Tags: vb.net

I am programming in Visual Basic and am creating a average calculator. The one thing I need to incorporate is an error message if the user inputs anything other than an integer into the textbox. My code looks like this.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        txtAverage.Text = Str((Val(txtTextBox1.Text) + Val(txtTextBox2.Text) + Val(txtTextBox3.Text) + Val(txtTextBox4.Text) + Val(txtTextBox5.Text)) / 5)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtTextBox1.Text = ""
        txtTextBox2.Text = ""
        txtTextBox3.Text = ""
        txtTextBox4.Text = ""
        txtTextBox5.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can use [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check each input value. Use it instead of `Val`. (Integer.TryParse is the same as Int32.TryParse.)

Comment: @Erowilder what are you developing for web, wpf, winforms cause according to the case you can use different methods to display an error message. Like in winforms you could use an error provider while in a website you can use various regex commands and in place attributes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a string variable has an integer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980538/check-if-a-string-variable-has-an-integer-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the input and calculate the average like this.

Create an array that contains all the TextBoxes you want to validate and then loop through the elements of the array. for each TextBox, use Integer.TryParse to check that the contents are valid and if so, convert to an integer. If the contents are not valid, a MessageBox is shown and the Sub exits. The individual numbers are added to an integer called total which is eventually used to calculate the average.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim boxes() As TextBox = {txtTextBox1, txtTextBox2, txtTextBox3, txtTextBox5, txtTextBox5}
    Dim total As Integer
    For Each box As TextBox In boxes
        Dim num As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(box.Text, num) Then
            total += num
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid number in " & box.Name)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    Dim average As Double = total / boxes.Length
    txtAverage.Text = average.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much blackwood. I am still new to the syntax of VB so this is all valuable information for me. thank you again!